# In d3.js line graph duration of animation is not align with provided value. And Using too much CPU processing

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js, optimization

Below is the code

```
type Data = {
  time: number;
  misalignment: number;
}[];
```

Original data array has more than 7000 data points this is an small sample.

```
const data: Data = [
  { time: 0, misalignment: -4.5891478772 },
  { time: 0, misalignment: -4.8211986847 },
  { time: 0, misalignment: -4.8211986847 },
]
```

draw function

```
createChart(data: Data) {
    console.log("inside createChart()");
    //console.log(this.chart);

    // Check if data is valid
    if (!this.isValidData(data)) {
      throw new Error('Invalid data');
    }

    // Declare the chart dimensions and margins.
    const width = 1800;
    const height = 700;
    const marginTop = 30;
    const marginRight = 40;
    const marginBottom = 30;
    const marginLeft = 40;

    // Declare the positional encodings.
    const xExtent: [number, number] = d3.extent(data, d => d.time) as [number, number];
    const x = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain(xExtent).nice()
      .range([marginLeft, width - marginRight]);

    const yExtent: [number, number] = d3.extent(data, d => d.misalignment) as [number, number];
    const y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain(yExtent).nice()
      .range([height - marginBottom, marginTop]);

    const line = d3.line()
      .curve(d3.curveCatmullRom)
      .x(d => x(d[0] as number))
      .y(d => y(d[1] as number));

    const svg = d3.select("#linechart")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
      .attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto;");

    const pathData = line(this.convertData(data));

    if (pathData) {

      let tickLabels = ['1:12', '2:24', '3:36', '4:48', '6:00'];
      svg.append("g")
        .style("font", "20px times")
        .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - marginBottom})`)
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("size", "20")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5)
          .tickValues([72000, 144000, 216000, 288000, 360000])
          .tickFormat((d, i) => tickLabels[i]))
        .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
        .call(g => g.selectAll(".tick line").clone()
          .attr("y2", -height)
          .attr("stroke-opacity", 1))
        .call(g => g.append("text")
          .attr("x", width - 4)
          .attr("y", -4)
          .attr("text-anchor", "end")
          .attr("fill", "black")
          .attr("font-size", "20")
          .text("Time from Start (Minutes)"));



      svg.append("g")
        .style("font", "20px times")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${marginLeft},0)`)
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null))
        .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
        .call(g => g.selectAll(".tick line").clone()
          .attr("x2", width)
          .attr("stroke-opacity", 1))
        .call(g => g.select(".tick:last-of-type text").clone()
          .attr("x", 4)
          .attr("text-anchor", "start")
          .attr("fill", "black")
          .attr("font-size", "25")
          .text("Misalignment"));


      svg.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "blue")
        .attr("stroke-width", 3.5)
        .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
        .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
        .attr("stroke-dasharray", `0,${pathData.length}`)
        .attr("d", pathData)
        .transition()
        .duration(100000)
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .attr("stroke-dasharray", `${pathData.length},${pathData.length}`);

      svg.append('line')
        .attr('x1', 385)
        .attr('y1', 700 - marginTop)
        .attr('x2', 385)
        .attr('y2', 0 + marginTop)
        .style("stroke-width", 5)
        .style("stroke", "orange")
        .style("fill", "none");

      
      
    } else {
      // Handle the case where pathData is null or undefined
      throw new Error('Path data is not available');
    }


  }

  // Function to check if data is valid
  isValidData(data: Data): boolean {
    const xExtent: [number, number] = d3.extent(data, d => d.time) as [number, number];
    const yExtent: [number, number] = d3.extent(data, d => d.misalignment) as [number, number];
    return !(isNaN(xExtent[0]) || isNaN(xExtent[1]) || isNaN(yExtent[0]) || isNaN(yExtent[1]));
  }

  convertData(data: Data): [number, number][] {
    return data.map(d => [d.time, d.misalignment]);
  }
```

as you can see duration of transition is 100000 milliseconds but on screen the whole graph is drawn in 6-7 (6000-7000 milliseconds) seconds only, and that's not the main issue  I want graph to be drawn in 5-6 seconds but browser keep using CPU for full '100000' milliseconds. that what I want to avoid.